# Boost property tree : how to get child of child tree with a xml file

Tags: c++, boost

I try to parse a simple xml file using Boost library (version 1.57.0.2) and I try to access to link field values.

Please find, here below my xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<down>
    <food name="cream">
        <link name="123" />
        <link name="456" />
    </food>
    <tel name="ice">
        <link name="78" />
        <link name="90" />
    </tel>
</down>
```

I try to see how to get child of child from web and do the same but I don't understand why it doesn't work with my code.

I have the following error :

```
error: 'const value_type {aka const struct std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >}' has no member named 'get_child'|
```

Please find my code here below :

```
boost::property_tree::xml_parser::read_xml(path.xml, tree);

BOOST_FOREACH(const boost::property_tree::ptree::value_type &child_tree, tree.get_child("down"))
{
    std::string tree_balise = tree.first;

    if (tree_balise == "food")
    {
        BOOST_FOREACH(const boost::property_tree::ptree::value_type &child_of_child_tree, child_tree.get_child("food"))
        {
            std::cout << "I am in the child of child tree" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Does somebody could tell me why this error appears ?
Am I missing something ?

Thank you for your help.

Miwa.

Comment: What line is emitting that error?

Comment: The following Line with the second boost_foreach, when i try to get the child of the child (child_tree.get_child("food"))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Actually `boost::property_tree::ptree::value_type` is a `pair` of `key_type` (`std::string` in your case) and `ptree`. So in 2nd `FOREACH` you have to use `child_tree.second` and error says that `pair` has no `get_child` member function.
2. In 2nd `FOREACH` scope you are already in "food" subtree. So it doesn't have "food" child.

   ```
   BOOST_FOREACH( const ptree::value_type & child_tree, tree.get_child("down") )
   {
       std::string tree_balise = child_tree.first;

       if (tree_balise == "food")
       {
           BOOST_FOREACH( const ptree::value_type & child_of_child_tree, child_tree.second )
           {
               std::cout << "I am in the child of child tree " << child_of_child_tree.first << std::endl;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Also Note that you can directly get "down.food" subtree.

```
BOOST_FOREACH( const ptree::value_type & child_tree, tree.get_child("down.food") )
{
    std::cout << "I am in the child of child tree " << child_tree.first << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Could I ask you something else ?

Comment: I try to access to my link attributs values with the following line : std::string value = child_tree.second.get<std::string>(boost:propertu_tree::xml_parser::xmlattr<std::string()>() + ".name")      but I crash when I run my executable. I think I'm not use correctly child_tree members functions, isn't it ?

Comment: @Miwa you can use `child_tree.second.get<std::string>("<xmlattr>.name")`.  But make sure that you are on `<link name="*" />` subtree and not in food's name attribute.  `if ( child_tree.first != "<xmlattr>" ) {
            std::cout << "I am in the child of child tree " << child_tree.second.get<std::string>("<xmlattr>.name") << std::endl;
        }`

Comment: yes I am sure I am on <link name="*" />, I have the following code :    'code'BOOST_FOREACH(const boost::property_tree::ptree::value_type &child_of_child_tree, child_tree.second)
{
std::string link_balise = child_of_child_tree.first ;
std::string iei_name;
if (link_balise != "<xmlattr>")
{
  std::cout << "I am in the child of child tree " << std::endl;
  std::string iei_name = child_of_the_child.second.get<std::string> (boost::property_tree::xml_parser::xmlattr<std::string>() + ".name");
 }'code' It is the same as yours, isn't it ?

Comment: Oh, I just replace get<std::string>(boost::property_tree::xml_parser::xmlattr<std::string>() + ".name"); by get<std::string>("<xmlattr>.name") and it works.... why ?...

Comment: @Miwa I am not sure what `boost::property_tree::xml_parser::xmlattr<std::string>()` is. you can read docs

Comment: @Miwa https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work